# FaceBook Data Security Best Practices and Authentication Issues

Tags: laravel, facebook

I manage a couple of older webapps that at some point have been converted to Laravel. They both allow login via email/password combinations or FaceBook logins, using Socialite for the latter.

FaceBook has advised me I need to confirm I meet the requirements for:

[A] Enforce encryption at rest for all Platform Data storage (e.g., all database files, backups, object storage buckets)

More clarification has not been forthcoming, and FB docs for developers tend to be self-referencing without really being clear. The inference here seems to be that any data provided by FaceBook via their API must be encrypted in the DB.

This can partly be achieved through casting certain User attributes to "encrypted" and applying this to the DB fields retrospectively for existing FB and non-FB users. However I don't see any obvious way of encrypting email address and still being able to use Laravel authentication in any fairly standard way. I can see how it could be made to work, though solutions seems to be onerous and rather awkward

As I find Laravel tends to offer straightforward ways of achieving routine functionality, and I don't think providing email/password logins is especially unusual, I'm surprised to find no information at all about how to work around this.

Am I mis-understanding the requirements here? Are others in a similar position not coming across these Data Protection Assessment requirements, or are they just telling FB "sure, everything's as it should be" and applying their own standard of security to user data?

I don't think this is off-topic or too vague, but appreciate it might be. If the question stays up, any advice is welcome.

Thanks

Edit:

Moved to github Laravel discussions

https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/42397

Answer (score 0):

If you examine firebase cms, you will understand better what you mean.
must be talking about encryption of repositories like automatic backup.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).